# UIwebview open document (pdf) in other app

Tags: pdf, uiwebview

Hello everyone,
               I am trying to open pdf file in uiwebview to other app. I can display popup like this.

[image: screen]

I write the code like this. I put delegate also. UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  //other code
 if([fileType isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
 {
     NSLog(@"It is pdf file.");
     //other code to save to nsdocumentdirectory and then get this path
     // file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/024D40FF-4518-4526-BEAB-   2A0679FD6308/Documents/iphone_user_guide.pdf

          NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToDownloadTo];
         UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pdfURL];

         [docController setDelegate:self];

         [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

 }
}

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return self;
}
```

I got this error. 
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

In some link, it say due to Javascript.  I also need to use this. stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

But I have disabled that function and tested. Then, there is no error but the app crashes.

I would like to know if there is something left to transfer document. 
Also, I would like to know how to add Uibarbutton like "Open in ibook or sth" in the uiwebview programmatically with some code as in safari when we open pdf file.

With Regards,